# Bootstrap Modal firing Show Event twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I am creating a modal and the event show is firing twice . The JS fiddle I have created for that also . 
Below is the code for the opening the modal

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Large Modal</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myModalBtn">Open Large Modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a large modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        console.log("open");
    });
    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        console.log("close");
    });
  $("#myModalBtn").on("click",function(){
      $("#myModal").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
$("#myModal").modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Just remove the `$("#myModal").modal('show');` because it shows the modal when initialized unless you pass the `show` option as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a reason you're not attaching the `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModal"` attributes to the button, but I'm not sure. So assuming you just want a regular modal button with a modal opening, you can add those two attributes to the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myModalBtn" 
    data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#myModal">Open Large Modal</button>
```

and also remove this section:

```
$("#myModalBtn").on("click",function(){
    $("#myModal").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

You can checkout the [bootstrap modal usage](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) to make sure your code matches the bootstrap standards.